SwiftUI view not properly updating
I'm obviously missing something huge but I can't understand why my FighterView isn't updating at all whenever I do any action like button tapping.
Here are my models :
class Fight: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fighter1: Fighter
    @Published var fighter2: Fighter

    init(fighter1: Fighter, fighter2: Fighter) {
        self.fighter1 = fighter1
        self.fighter2 = fighter2
    }

    func resetFight() {
        fighter1.reset()
        fighter2.reset()
    }
}

class Fighter: ObservableObject {

    @Published var name: String = ""    
    @Published var wazaari = 0
    /* some more variables */

    func reset() {
        // Set all data to default values
    }
}

And here are my views :
struct BoardView: View {
    
    @StateObject var fight = Fight(fighter1: Fighter(),
                                   fighter2: Fighter())
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                TopBarView() // TopBarView contains a reset button so I can see that data is properly updated when I change the name or increase the wazaari value
                
                FighterView(fighter: $fight.fighter1)
                
                FighterView(fighter: $fight.fighter2)

                BottomBarView()
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(fight)
    }
}

struct FighterView: View {
    
    @Binding var fighter: Fighter

    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            
            TextField("Placeholder", text: $fighter.name)
                .onChange(of: fighter.name) { oldValue, newValue in
                    fighter.name = newValue
                }
            Button(action: {
                guard fighter.wazaari < 2 else { return }
                
                fighter.wazaari += 1
                print(fighter.wazaari)
            }, label: {
                Text("\(fighter.wazaari)")
            })
            .buttonStyle(PointButton())
            
       }
    }
}

I use environmentObject cause I want to access my fight data from any of my subviews (TopBarView, FighterView, BottomBarView). The values are properly modified when I put text in my textfield or tap the button in the FighterView but the view isn't updating at all.
Any clue ?

Nesting  ObservableObject is not a great idea. I suggest you use the more modern @Observable class that replaces ObservableObject.
Such as:
@Observable class Fight {      var fighter1: Fighter  .... Similarly for Fighter.
See Migrating from the Observable Object protocol to the Observable macro. A simple change that caters for nesting.

Thanks I will definitely dig this and do the update :)
